# How to generating security nonces from WordPress

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, flutterflow

I have read [Woocommerce Nonce Token](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/blob/trunk/src/StoreApi/docs/nonce-tokens.md#generating-security-nonces-from-wordpress)

Could you help to show me where to get the right Nonce Token by using this? `wp_create_nonce( 'wc_store_api' )`

My low code mobile app builder support only API call as RESTfull APi, and I can call to Woocommerce API successful by Customer Key & Secret Key but for [Woocommerce Store APi](https://developer.woocommerce.com/2022/03/25/store-api-is-now-considered-stable/) it extra step required Nonce Token.